# Using Flutter and Redux or AsyncRedux, how can I uncouple widgets from the app state?

Tags: flutter, redux, reactive-programming, state-management, async-redux

Suppose that a **Flutter** app uses **Redux** for its state management ([flutter_redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) or [async_redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async_redux)).

The state is in a class `AppState`, and the store is `Store<AppState>` (for example like this: http://flutterbyexample.com/app-state-model).

Then container widgets use the `StoreConnector<AppState, ...>`, that depend on `AppState`.
These widgets get tightly coupled with `AppState`. Then how can I reuse the widgets in other apps, since other apps have a different `AppState`?

How can I even develop and test the container widgets separately from each other, if the widgets depend on `AppState`, and `AppState` is common among them?

Answer (score 2):

[In this blog post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/89dtcp/introduction_to_redux_in_flutter/) I explain how to start using Redux with Flutter.

As you can see from the code example, you can create a `ViewModel` class instead of coupling your `Widget`s to the `State`, meaning that if you create a `ViewModel` class for each `Widget` that you're planning to reuse, you should be able to create test `ViewModel` objects for testing and also reuse those `Widget`s in multiple projects.

EDIT:

You could create a `State` class which is specific to that `Widget` (i.e. `ToggleState` and compose your application `State` class with a `ToggleState` object:

```
class AppState {
  final ToggleWidgetState onOffState;
}

class ToggleWidgetState {
  final bool isOn;
}
```

and your `ViewModel` could be created from that `ToggleWidgetState` instead of the whole `AppState`, so try to compose your app state from various smaller state objects.

Comment: That's actually what I am doing at the moment. But the `ViewModel` is coupled to the state. The `ViewModel` is not considered part of the widget? For example, if some toggle button can be on or off when clicked, it actually does not turn on/off without the correct `ViewModel` that wires its state to the button tap callback.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean now, I've edited my answer to explain how I'd do it in that case, since code formatting doesn't work in comments

Comment: I thought about that. But if the store is created by `store = Store<AppState>` I must later do `new StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>`. I don't see how I can do `new StoreConnector<ToggleWidgetState, _ViewModel>`.

Comment: I'm wondering if for your case it might be worth looking into Flux (to have multiple states) rather using Redux https://github.com/google/flutter_flux

Answer (score 1):

I think truly reusable components are only the `presentational` one.

These are components in which there is no state management (no `StoreConnector`, no `StoreBuilder`...).

**Presentational component example**:

```
class ExampleItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final Example example;

  ExampleItem({   
    @required this.example,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(        
        title: Hero(
          tag: '${example.id}__heroTag',
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text(
              example.name,
              key: ExampleKeys.exampleItemName(example.id),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
          ),
        ),      
      );   
  }
}
```

**Container component example**:

```
class ExampleContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  ExampleContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>(     
      converter: _ViewModel.fromStore,
      builder: (context, vm) {
        return ExampleList(
          list: vm.list,        
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ViewModel {
  final List<Example> list;

  _ViewModel({this.list});

  static _ViewModel fromStore(Store<AppState> store) {
    return _ViewModel(list: listSelector(store.state));
  }
}
```